# Possible to solve this function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, variable

I have this function:

```
Emax[T_, d_] := -(1/2) + d + d/(-1 + E^(d/T)) - 1/2 Coth[1/(2 T)];
```

All I want is to transform this Function so I get:

```
T[Emax_, d_] := .....
```

I just want to be able to put in Emax and d value and get the correspoding T. If tried doing tables and stuff but it doesn't work as I would want it to:/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mathematica can't invert that equation exactly. Is an approximation acceptable? around which values? (I assume you mean `Exp[(d/T)]`)

Comment: Exact solutions, if they exist, can be found for specific values using constructs like `t /. Solve[1 == Emax[t, 7/3], t, Reals]`. Also, you probably want to replace `e` with `E`. You can also find equation solutions for specific values of `d`: `InverseFunction[Emax[#, 2] &]`

Comment: @rhermans
Hm, I guess an approximation would be a good start.

Comment: @kirma
Ok, I'll try that out and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
einv = InverseFunction[-(1/2) + d + d/(-1 + E^(d/#)) - 1/2 Coth[1/(2 #)] &]
```

To use this, you need to specify a value of d, for example:

```
N[einv[5] /. d -> 5]
N[einv[0] /. d -> 1]
```

To plot, you can do something like:

```
e2[dval_] = Abs[N[einv[0] /. d -> dval]];
ListPlot[e2[#] & /@ Range[1, 10, 0.1]]
```

[image]

Of course, you can also change the "0" to a range of values.

Comment: Thanks but the thing is I need this thing to be dynamic :/

I am using a manipulate[Plot[...] {d,1,10},{Emax,1,10}] where I change d or Emax constanantly. That's why I want a function for T, to get constantly a new T which corresponds to any d or Emax I currently have. 
Understand what I mean?

Comment: Your question explicitly states: "I just want to be able to put in Emax and d value and get the correspoding T."

Answer (score 1):

The numerical function T[em,d]:

```
solT[em_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := T /. NMinimize[{1, 
{T > 0,em == -(1/2) + d + d/(-1 + Exp[d/T]) - 1/2 Coth[1/(2 T)]}},T][[2]]

solT[3, 2]
(*0.0259196*)
```

Comment: This worked very nice! Thanks, I'm finally making some progress.

But I ran into a few issues :/

1. Numerical solutions are not continous. It's possible that for certain combinations of em and d there will be no value for T which would cause the programm to crash. Ideas ?

2. The thing is I am trying to use this function in a plot in which I continously can change values of em and d. This causes massive lag. For single values it's fine though.

3. Would it be rather possible to get a simpler/continous **approximation** for the value of T?

Comment: And last but not least:

I was trying to use certain values for solT

solT[List[a,b,c][[2]], d]

For d it worked fine in the plot since d is one of the dynamical variables I can change. 

But apparently taking one certain entry from List which looks sth. like this:
{10,7,5,6,3} and what I did with List[[2]] was to single the value 7 out, has the wrong format or something. Either way I connot use it for solT[List[[2]],d] to get vaules. 

Any ideas how to change the format ? Thanks

Comment: `solT[{0.1, .5, .62}[[3]], 2]` works! So your second question seems to be an issue of Dynamic variables?

Comment: Your first question: If you plot `Emax[d,T]` let's say in the range `0<T<5` for `d=Range[ 1,3,.1}`you get the region of admissable parametervalues. In this region the solution T exists and the numerical function solT will find T!

Comment: Hm I see, then yes it must be a problem with the Dynamical Variable. 

You see all I want is to use the solT[em,d] Value is in a plot as Limit for the manipulate variable T.

So in a Sense I want 



    Manipulate[ListPlot[MinVar[T, R, d], {T, 1,**solT[em, d]**}, {R, 10, 20},{d,10,20}] 



Now d is easy because it is also a manipulate variable. But for em I need a value from another dynamical List that is changing constantly as I change the manipulate variables.

Comment: And I know for a fact that the List is working because I have the desired number displayed next to my plot so I can see how it changes when I change the manipulate variables. MinVar being the other List that constantly changes, which has the value I need in it.

Epilog -> { Text[Style["Case: " <> ToString[Round[MinVar[T, R, d][[6]]]] }

I can see it change. So now I wanted to take MinVar[T, R, d][[6]] and put it into solT. 

Manipulate[ListPlot[MinVar[T, R, d], {T, 1,**solT[MinVar[T, R, d][[6]] , d**]}, {R, 10, 20},{d,10,20}]

But it doesn't work :/ Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: So I tested it out and yes. The Problem is the Variable T.

Maybe I can't define the Limit of T as Variable of T. I get the error message:


Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument {T,0.5,funct2[MinVarGeneralThermal[T,R,d][[6]],d],0.1} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

But as soon as I define the limit like this:

 Manipulate[ListPlot[MinVar[T, R, d], {T, 1,**solT[MinVar[1, R, d][[6]] , d**]}, {R, 10, 20},{d,10,20}]

Where I replaced the T with a 1 it works.